# ubuntu broken python installation by mistake

Tags: python, ubuntu, system-administration

I've tried to update Python and I didn't know about isollation of version instead delete the versions, so, I've deleted all of my Python version inside my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS. Now i'm not able to install nothing trough apt-get.

:

```
root@vps15:/# apt-get install --reinstall python3.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to install manually to source Python 2.7 to /usr/lib and that works now, but the problem now is this dependency: "dh-python".

```
# apt-get install python3.5-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
python3.5-minimal is already the newest version (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.5-minimal : Depends: libpython3.5-minimal (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: python3.5 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried all the methods listed and I can't fix the dependencies.

Before trying the fixing, the problem was Python2.7 instead python3, now python3 by manual installation didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Might be a better question for AskUbuntu

Comment: this may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065556/broken-python-dependencies-after-trying-to-re-install

Comment: I tried that guide @NikolayPatarov but didn't work. Post the correct answer after this thread. Thanks!

Comment: @chemicalwill true, anyway it's fixed now, the solution is posted now for the community. I was going around this all the week

Comment: Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some more research, I've founded a post related to Debian. Handling some modifications for Ubuntu 16.04, tried this guide and works everything now:

## Step 1.

```
cd /tmp
apt-get download libpython3.5-minimal
apt-get download python3.5-minimal
apt-get download python3-minimal
apt-get download libpython3.5-stdlib
apt-get download python3.5
```

## Step 2.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5*
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3.5*
update-alternatives --remove python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.5
hash -r  # removes cached python3 binary path
```

## Step 3.

```
cd /tmp
dpkg-deb -x libpython3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.13_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.13_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x python3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.13_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.13_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x python3-minimal_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb missing
```

## Step 4.

```
cd /tmp/missing
ls -lR /tmp/missing  # if you are curious about overwriting your HD
sudo cp -rpfv /tmp/missing/*  /
```

## Step 5.

```
python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Import and test new version:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>>
>>> quit()
```

## Step 6.

```
rm -rf /tmp/missing
```

## Step 7.

```
dpkg -s -a python3.5 | grep  reinstreq
# Any listing also needs to be reinstalled along with python3
apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

## Step 8.

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
# (see the packages that will autoremove, you need to reinstall it again after: apt-get install --fix-broken --reinstall <<packages>>)
```

## Step 9.

Try to install common prop.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

If it works, now the installation is done.

---

I've tried this for Ubuntu 16.04, with working Python2.7 installation but not with Python3, or Python3.5. The original installation I've was for Python3.5, that's why tried to install that version instead newest.

Comment: Thank you @kirst ! I done your steps for python3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 using https://pkgs.org for searching of full package names. It fixed not only python3 but lot of other stuff like gnome-terminal and settings of Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Thank you @AndriyPlokhotnyuk. It took to me a lot of time to find a good solution..

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: @DiretnanDomnan I'll edit the post and take care about that, i guess some of users will glad about that

Comment: We are told this is impossible and to reinstall the OS... This needs to become an article.
I got it to work for me on ubuntu 22.04 with Python3.10.

Comment: @Gaby_64 ty for your comment, glad to help others. Took me a lot of time to resolve by myself :(

Comment: @maxirodr Just used this on Ubuntu 20.04 to reinstall Python 3.8 after apt purging it by mistake. Saved my day - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me to the root cause. For me the issue was broken `distro_info` package installed by `pip` and `pip` itself was so broken that I could not uninstall the package via `pip uninstall`. I removed `/usr/local/lib/python3.8` so `do-release-upgrade` would use the original Ubuntu packages under `/usr/lib/python3.8`. This solved the issue. I was updating from 20.04 => 22.04.